# How to solve the drdy err in the boot stage on my debian8?

Tags: boot

There is a drdy err in the boot stage on my debian8 for about one weeks.
How to solve it ?

[image]

```
tail /var/log/messages
Nov 10 14:44:11 hws kernel: [ 5105.118918] scsi 5:0:0:0: CDB:
Nov 10 14:44:11 hws kernel: [ 5105.118921] Inquiry: 12 00 00 00 24 00
Nov 10 14:44:12 hws kernel: [ 5106.118572] scsi 5:0:0:0: CDB:
Nov 10 14:44:12 hws kernel: [ 5106.118575] Inquiry: 12 00 00 00 24 00
Nov 10 14:44:13 hws kernel: [ 5107.118231] scsi 5:0:0:0: CDB:
Nov 10 14:44:13 hws kernel: [ 5107.118234] Inquiry: 12 00 00 00 24 00
Nov 10 14:44:14 hws kernel: [ 5108.117897] scsi 5:0:0:0: CDB:
Nov 10 14:44:14 hws kernel: [ 5108.117899] Inquiry: 12 00 00 00 24 00
Nov 10 14:44:15 hws kernel: [ 5109.117598] scsi 5:0:0:0: CDB:
Nov 10 14:44:15 hws kernel: [ 5109.117600] Inquiry: 12 00 00 00 24 00
```

Answer (score 2):

Form [Ubuntu Forms](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1034762):

> It's Kernel bug on ata acpi. Put "options libata noacpi=1" on /etc/modprobe.d/options

Give that a go and see if it helps. (Yes, I know you are running Debian, but Ubuntu is based off of debian and they run the same, if not very similar Kernels)

Hope this helps!

Comment: cat  /etc/modprobe.d/options

Comment: cat: /etc/modprobe.d/options: No such file or directory

Comment: How can i do now?

Answer (score 0):

The sata3 device was inserted into sata6 slot in my pc,i inserted it sata3 slot,error info dispear.

Comment: It is called `SATA II` and `SATA III` most people would not understand what you meant by `SATA 3` and `SATA 6`